# EXCEL 2010, vertical search, parse cell

Tags: search, excel-2010, vlookup

I need help with vertical search in Excel 2010.
I have a document with two sheets, in each sheet is one table containing data ...

```
sheet one
A    B     C     D
123  sth   sth   'need to find and copy value from second sheet(key is collumn A); formula here
321
678
845
983

sheet two
A          B        C
123, 321   sth      100 'looking for this value, copy 100 to first sheet to key 123 and also 321
678                 99  'value for key 678 in sheet one
845, 983            82  'value for keys 845 and 983 in sheet one ..
```

I use vlookup(), but when I have two values separated with comma in one cell it doesn't work and I have to do it manually. 
Is there a function something like vlookup which I can combine with left() and right() functions, or do I have to use something more sophisticated, a VB macro?
I cannot change layouts of these sheets ...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array formula with SEARCH?

```
{=IF(SEARCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A),Sheet2!D:D)}
```

slightly more comprehensive version of that:

```
{=SUM(IF( NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A))),Sheet2!D:D))}
```

as mentioned by Nanashi, you can change sum to average or whatever you like handle multiple values

You need to use ctrl+shift+enter to make a formula an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Rather hacky solution that uses formulas only.

Enter in `Sheet1!C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet1!$A1)=1,VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1,Sheet2!$A:$C,3,FALSE),SUMIF(Sheet2!$A:$A,"*"&Sheet1!$A1&"*",Sheet2!$C:$C))
```

Sample result:

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Disclaimer:**

This method is very easy to break. One possible failing is that if there are no spaces between the IDs in `Sheet2`, the formula fails. Also, if by any chance the ID repeats in `Sheet2`, they will be added due to the usage of `SUMIF`. A workaround is to use `AVERAGEIF` instead.